# Garbled audio when starts playing then clears up CentOS 7.3

Tags: centos, audio, alsa

When I first start playing an audio clip I get distorted sound then clears up. This behavior is consistent for all audio or video applications i.e. vlc, aplay, youtube etc.

I have tried solutions as follows:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/snd_hda_intel.conf
    options snd_hda_intel power_save=0
```

```
$ sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel power_save=0
$ sudo /usr/bin/amixer -c 1 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled
```

Here is output of `lspci`:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep -i audio
    00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
    01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

Here is `/proc/modules`:

```
$ cat /proc/modules | grep -i intel
ghash_clmulni_intel 13259 0 - Live 0xffffffffa123b000
aesni_intel 69884 0 - Live 0xffffffffa1156000
lrw 13286 1 aesni_intel, Live 0xffffffffa10e3000
glue_helper 13990 1 aesni_intel, Live 0xffffffffa1123000
ablk_helper 13597 1 aesni_intel, Live 0xffffffffa10ec000
cryptd 20359 3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper, Live 0xffffffffa10ce000
snd_hda_intel 39987 7 - Live 0xffffffffa10f1000
snd_hda_codec 136428 4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel, Live 0xffffffffa1100000
snd_hda_core 85362 5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec, Live 0xffffffffa10af000
snd_pcm 106416 4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core, Live 0xffffffffa1082000
snd 83432 24            snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel, snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm,snd_timer, Live 0xffffffffa0e23000
crc32c_intel 22079 1 - Live 0xffffffffa00b3000
```

I have tried suggestions on https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_sound_problems

Still cannot eliminate the issue. Has anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an analog or a digital output?

Comment: If you are using Pulseaudio, first step is to stop Pulseaudio completely (verify with `ps`) and use ALSA directly (`aplay -D front:foo`, `aplay -L` for available devices) to take Pulseaudio out of the equation and find out if the problem is Pulseaudio, or ALSA/drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I powered down the computer instead of reset or reboot and issue went away.

the steps:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/snd_hda_intel.conf
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0
```

then:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel power_save=0
```

works just need to power down instead of reboot.